# Show/hide column in rich:extendedDataTable (RichFaces 4.x)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

RichFaces' show/hide column feature for `rich:extendedDataTable` is not available any more for the version 4.x.
Any ideas how to implement it in some other way?

I tried to do it using JavaScript, with the `document.getElementById()` function and setting the element's `style.display` property, but it is hard to locate an element by id since all elements in `rich:table` are generated dynamically.

Any help and hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not very sure of how it can be done..But you can try using JQuery for this purpose..Infact I am also trying my hands on JQuery..You can define a class or a div and then show or hide this class or div..I am not sure whether same can be achieved using jquery or not but you can surely give it a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Richfaces 4.x extendedDataTable, you could use css style to control both the header and body of that column in the same time. The css style of each column is created with the prefix ".rf-edt-c-" and column id. If you have a column with id "column1", the css style will be ".rf-edt-c-column1". The following is an example to hide/show the column with column id in Java Script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 

    function hideColumn(columnId)
    {
        var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
        for(var i=0;i<styleSheets.length;i++)
        {
            var rules = null;

            // IE and Chrome
            if(styleSheets[i].rules != null)
            {
                rules = styleSheets[i].rules;
            }
            // Firefox
            else if(styleSheets[i].cssRules != null)
            {
                rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules;
            }

            for(var j=0;j<rules.length;j++)
            {
                // Find the css style of that column
                if(rules[j].selectorText==".rf-edt-c-" + columnId)
                {
                    rules[j].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function showColumn(columnId)
    {
        var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
        for(var i=0;i<styleSheets.length;i++)
        {
            var rules = null;

            // IE and Chrome
            if(styleSheets[i].rules != null)
            {
                rules = styleSheets[i].rules;
            }
            // Firefox
            else if(styleSheets[i].cssRules != null)
            {
                rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules;
            }

            for(var j=0;j<rules.length;j++)
            {
                // Find the css style of that column
                if(rules[j].selectorText==".rf-edt-c-" + columnId)
                {
                    rules[j].style.display = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you for your answer. I asked my question almost two years ago and already solved the problem (actually avoided need to implement it), but anyway I will try it when have time. I will also mark your answer as accepted (also because your answer is the only promising one).

Answer (score -1):

Just put the attribute `visible="false"` in `the rich:column` tag like this:

```xml
<rich:column id="name" label="Name" sortable="true" sortBy="#{edt.name}" visible="false">
```

Wrong RichFaces version, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I add this in `rich:column` attributes:

```
width="#{myBean.testDisplay('toDisplay')?'':'0px;border:none;'}"
```

It is better than using `rendered` because `rendered` bugs with the columns rearrangement.

Comment: Please edit your answer to format code correctly and explain your answer so the asker can understand why this code works better.